# Puppeteer getting element from elementHandle causing protocol error

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm trying to scrape a certain facebook page for its posts written by a certain user and starting with a certain word.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function findPosts(page) {
    const USERNAME = 'test123';
    const posts = await page.$$('.userContentWrapper');
    return posts.filter(async post => {
        try {
            let usernameElement = await post.$('.fwb');
            let username = await page.evaluate(element => element.textContent, usernameElement);
            if (username === USERNAME) {
                let postElement = await post.$('[data-testid="post_message"] p');
                let postContent = page.evaluate(element => element.textContent, postElement);
                return /\[test \d+\]/.test(postContent);
            }
            return false;
        } catch(e) {
            console.log(e);
            return false;
        }
    });
}


(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://www.facebook.com/groups/groupid/');
    const pageTitle = await page.title();
    console.log(pageTitle);
    const posts = await findPosts(page);
    console.log(posts);
    await browser.close();
})();
```

I'm getting

> Error: Protocol error (Runtime.callFunctionOn): Target closed. when
>   I'm trying to get the usernameElement

at this line:

> let usernameElement = await post.$('.fwb');

Not sure what's going wrong here, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function does not work with Promises. So the `return posts.filter(...)` will immediately return and after that the browser is closed. Therefore, when you try to run the `$` function on the page, the page does not exist anymore and you get the `Target closed` error.

To make it work with async/await syntax, you could use a simple loop instead:

```js
async function findPosts(page) {
    const USERNAME = 'test123';
    const posts = await page.$$('.userContentWrapper');
    const postsToReturn = [];
    for (let post of posts) {
        /* ... if else logic */
        postsToReturn.push(post); // instead of return true
    }
    return postsToReturn;
}
```